# Error: "Client-SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: string '%PDF-1.4 %\xc7...' is not a valid utf-8 string"

Tags: php, web-services

when i am try to upload a pdf file Using  WebService API's  i got this error

> " Client-SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: string '%PDF-1.4 %\xc7...' is not a
>   valid utf-8 string".

Answer (score 0):

Yes - one or t'other end of the service is not coded correctly.

It's impossible without seeing the full XML for both ends and the WSDL to determine which - but most likely, the service requires a UTF-8 encoded content and your client is not checking what it's actually sending - in which case base64 encode the file and tell the remote system that's how its encoded.

C.

Answer (score 0):

Your SOAP webservice is waiting for `UTF-8` string only.
I just solved the same issue using `utf8_encode($mystring)` (the string I'm sending comes from an `iso-8859-1` encoded file)